# "brew: Command not found" after fresh install with csh, PATH is correct

Tags: bash, macos, homebrew, csh

I was simply trying to update `bash` on my macOS Mojave system by following [this article](https://itnext.io/upgrading-bash-on-macos-7138bd1066ba), and stupidly deleted the old `bash` binary and tried to replace it with `sudo mv /usr/local/bin/bash /bin/bash`. This created a myriad of other problems, most of which I have fixed with `cp /bin/csh /bin/bash` and `chsh -s /bin/csh`, then `rm -f /bin/bash`.

I have since tried **three times** to uninstall and reinstall homebrew (albeit without the use of Ruby and with a file redirect being necessary).

#### TL;DR:

I'm guessing this has something to do with the line shown below: `find: /bin/bash: No such file or directory`. The install also fails with `Failed during: /usr/local/bin/brew update --force` and trying to run an update manually gives the `brew: Command not found` error. `echo $PATH` returns `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin` and I'm running all of these commands directly from `/usr/local/bin` anyway. So what gives?! MTIA :-)

#### Full Terminal output:

```
[Kents-MacBook-Pro:/usr/local/bin] Kenny% ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
Illegal variable name.
[Kents-MacBook-Pro:/usr/local/bin] Kenny% curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall > uninstall.sh
[Kents-MacBook-Pro:/usr/local/bin] Kenny% chmod +x uninstall.sh 
[Kents-MacBook-Pro:/usr/local/bin] Kenny% ./uninstall.sh
Warning: This script will remove:
/Users/Kenny/Library/Caches/Homebrew/
/usr/local/Caskroom/
/usr/local/Cellar/
/usr/local/Homebrew/
/usr/local/Homebrew/.editorconfig
/usr/local/Homebrew/.github/
/usr/local/Homebrew/.gitignore
/usr/local/Homebrew/.yardopts
/usr/local/Homebrew/CHANGELOG.md
/usr/local/Homebrew/CONTRIBUTING.md
/usr/local/Homebrew/Dockerfile
/usr/local/Homebrew/LICENSE.txt
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/
/usr/local/Homebrew/README.md
/usr/local/Homebrew/bin/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew/completions/
/usr/local/Homebrew/docs/
/usr/local/Homebrew/manpages/
/usr/local/bin/brew -> /usr/local/Homebrew/bin/brew
/usr/local/var/homebrew/
Are you sure you want to uninstall Homebrew? This will remove your installed packages! [y/N] y
==> Removing Homebrew installation...
find: /bin/bash: No such file or directory
==> Removing empty directories...
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/find /usr/local/bin /usr/local/etc /usr/local/include /usr/local/lib /usr/local/opt /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/share /usr/local/var /usr/local/Frameworks -name .DS_Store -delete
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/find /usr/local/bin /usr/local/etc /usr/local/include /usr/local/lib /usr/local/opt /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/share /usr/local/var /usr/local/Frameworks -depth -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} ;
==> Homebrew uninstalled!
The following possible Homebrew files were not deleted:
/usr/local/bin/
/usr/local/.com.apple.installer.keep
/usr/local/libexec/
/usr/local/microsoft/
/usr/local/include/
/usr/local/sbin/
/usr/local/remotedesktop/
/usr/local/etc/
/usr/local/lib/
/usr/local/opt/
/usr/local/git/
/usr/local/share/
You may wish to remove them yourself.
[Kents-MacBook-Pro:/usr/local/bin] Kenny% curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install > install.sh
[Kents-MacBook-Pro:/usr/local/bin] Kenny% chmod +x install.sh
[Kents-MacBook-Pro:/usr/local/bin] Kenny% ./install.sh
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew
==> The following new directories will be created:
/usr/local/var
/usr/local/share/zsh
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
/usr/local/var/homebrew
/usr/local/var/homebrew/linked
/usr/local/Cellar
/usr/local/Caskroom
/usr/local/Homebrew
/usr/local/Frameworks

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/var /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/local/var/homebrew /usr/local/var/homebrew/linked /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/Caskroom /usr/local/Homebrew /usr/local/Frameworks
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod g+rwx /usr/local/var /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/local/var/homebrew /usr/local/var/homebrew/linked /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/Caskroom /usr/local/Homebrew /usr/local/Frameworks
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod 755 /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown Kenny /usr/local/var /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/local/var/homebrew /usr/local/var/homebrew/linked /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/Caskroom /usr/local/Homebrew /usr/local/Frameworks
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/chgrp admin /usr/local/var /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/local/var/homebrew /usr/local/var/homebrew/linked /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/Caskroom /usr/local/Homebrew /usr/local/Frameworks
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /Users/Kenny/Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod g+rwx /Users/Kenny/Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown Kenny /Users/Kenny/Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
remote: Enumerating objects: 127973, done.
remote: Total 127973 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 127973
Receiving objects: 100% (127973/127973), 30.42 MiB | 4.88 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (93909/93909), done.
From https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
 * [new tag]         0.1        -> 0.1
 * [new tag]         0.2        -> 0.2
 * [new tag]         0.3        -> 0.3
 * [new tag]         0.4        -> 0.4
 * [new tag]         0.5        -> 0.5
 * [new tag]         0.6        -> 0.6
 * [new tag]         0.7        -> 0.7
 * [new tag]         0.7.1      -> 0.7.1
 * [new tag]         0.8        -> 0.8
 * [new tag]         0.8.1      -> 0.8.1
 * [new tag]         0.9        -> 0.9
 * [new tag]         0.9.1      -> 0.9.1
 * [new tag]         0.9.2      -> 0.9.2
 * [new tag]         0.9.3      -> 0.9.3
 * [new tag]         0.9.4      -> 0.9.4
 * [new tag]         0.9.5      -> 0.9.5
 * [new tag]         0.9.8      -> 0.9.8
 * [new tag]         0.9.9      -> 0.9.9
 * [new tag]         1.0.0      -> 1.0.0
 * [new tag]         1.0.1      -> 1.0.1
 * [new tag]         1.0.2      -> 1.0.2
 * [new tag]         1.0.3      -> 1.0.3
 * [new tag]         1.0.4      -> 1.0.4
 * [new tag]         1.0.5      -> 1.0.5
 * [new tag]         1.0.6      -> 1.0.6
 * [new tag]         1.0.7      -> 1.0.7
 * [new tag]         1.0.8      -> 1.0.8
 * [new tag]         1.0.9      -> 1.0.9
 * [new tag]         1.1.0      -> 1.1.0
 * [new tag]         1.1.1      -> 1.1.1
 * [new tag]         1.1.10     -> 1.1.10
 * [new tag]         1.1.11     -> 1.1.11
 * [new tag]         1.1.12     -> 1.1.12
 * [new tag]         1.1.13     -> 1.1.13
 * [new tag]         1.1.2      -> 1.1.2
 * [new tag]         1.1.3      -> 1.1.3
 * [new tag]         1.1.4      -> 1.1.4
 * [new tag]         1.1.5      -> 1.1.5
 * [new tag]         1.1.6      -> 1.1.6
 * [new tag]         1.1.7      -> 1.1.7
 * [new tag]         1.1.8      -> 1.1.8
 * [new tag]         1.1.9      -> 1.1.9
 * [new tag]         1.2.0      -> 1.2.0
 * [new tag]         1.2.1      -> 1.2.1
 * [new tag]         1.2.2      -> 1.2.2
 * [new tag]         1.2.3      -> 1.2.3
 * [new tag]         1.2.4      -> 1.2.4
 * [new tag]         1.2.5      -> 1.2.5
 * [new tag]         1.2.6      -> 1.2.6
 * [new tag]         1.3.0      -> 1.3.0
 * [new tag]         1.3.1      -> 1.3.1
 * [new tag]         1.3.2      -> 1.3.2
 * [new tag]         1.3.3      -> 1.3.3
 * [new tag]         1.3.4      -> 1.3.4
 * [new tag]         1.3.5      -> 1.3.5
 * [new tag]         1.3.6      -> 1.3.6
 * [new tag]         1.3.7      -> 1.3.7
 * [new tag]         1.3.8      -> 1.3.8
 * [new tag]         1.3.9      -> 1.3.9
 * [new tag]         1.4.0      -> 1.4.0
 * [new tag]         1.4.1      -> 1.4.1
 * [new tag]         1.4.2      -> 1.4.2
 * [new tag]         1.4.3      -> 1.4.3
 * [new tag]         1.5.0      -> 1.5.0
 * [new tag]         1.5.1      -> 1.5.1
 * [new tag]         1.5.10     -> 1.5.10
 * [new tag]         1.5.11     -> 1.5.11
 * [new tag]         1.5.12     -> 1.5.12
 * [new tag]         1.5.13     -> 1.5.13
 * [new tag]         1.5.14     -> 1.5.14
 * [new tag]         1.5.2      -> 1.5.2
 * [new tag]         1.5.3      -> 1.5.3
 * [new tag]         1.5.4      -> 1.5.4
 * [new tag]         1.5.5      -> 1.5.5
 * [new tag]         1.5.6      -> 1.5.6
 * [new tag]         1.5.7      -> 1.5.7
 * [new tag]         1.5.8      -> 1.5.8
 * [new tag]         1.5.9      -> 1.5.9
 * [new tag]         1.6.0      -> 1.6.0
 * [new tag]         1.6.1      -> 1.6.1
 * [new tag]         1.6.10     -> 1.6.10
 * [new tag]         1.6.11     -> 1.6.11
 * [new tag]         1.6.12     -> 1.6.12
 * [new tag]         1.6.13     -> 1.6.13
 * [new tag]         1.6.14     -> 1.6.14
 * [new tag]         1.6.15     -> 1.6.15
 * [new tag]         1.6.16     -> 1.6.16
 * [new tag]         1.6.17     -> 1.6.17
 * [new tag]         1.6.2      -> 1.6.2
 * [new tag]         1.6.3      -> 1.6.3
 * [new tag]         1.6.4      -> 1.6.4
 * [new tag]         1.6.5      -> 1.6.5
 * [new tag]         1.6.6      -> 1.6.6
 * [new tag]         1.6.7      -> 1.6.7
 * [new tag]         1.6.8      -> 1.6.8
 * [new tag]         1.6.9      -> 1.6.9
 * [new tag]         1.7.0      -> 1.7.0
 * [new tag]         1.7.1      -> 1.7.1
 * [new tag]         1.7.2      -> 1.7.2
 * [new tag]         1.7.3      -> 1.7.3
 * [new tag]         1.7.4      -> 1.7.4
 * [new tag]         1.7.5      -> 1.7.5
 * [new tag]         1.7.6      -> 1.7.6
 * [new tag]         1.7.7      -> 1.7.7
 * [new tag]         1.8.0      -> 1.8.0
 * [new tag]         1.8.1      -> 1.8.1
 * [new tag]         1.8.2      -> 1.8.2
 * [new tag]         1.8.3      -> 1.8.3
 * [new tag]         1.8.4      -> 1.8.4
 * [new tag]         1.8.5      -> 1.8.5
 * [new tag]         1.8.6      -> 1.8.6
 * [new tag]         1.9.0      -> 1.9.0
 * [new tag]         1.9.1      -> 1.9.1
 * [new tag]         1.9.2      -> 1.9.2
 * [new tag]         1.9.3      -> 1.9.3
 * [new tag]         2.0.0      -> 2.0.0
 * [new tag]         2.0.1      -> 2.0.1
 * [new tag]         2.0.2      -> 2.0.2
 * [new tag]         2.0.3      -> 2.0.3
 * [new tag]         2.0.4      -> 2.0.4
 * [new tag]         2.0.5      -> 2.0.5
 * [new tag]         2.0.6      -> 2.0.6
 * [new tag]         2.1.0      -> 2.1.0
 * [new tag]         2.1.1      -> 2.1.1
 * [new tag]         2.1.10     -> 2.1.10
 * [new tag]         2.1.11     -> 2.1.11
 * [new tag]         2.1.12     -> 2.1.12
 * [new tag]         2.1.13     -> 2.1.13
 * [new tag]         2.1.14     -> 2.1.14
 * [new tag]         2.1.15     -> 2.1.15
 * [new tag]         2.1.2      -> 2.1.2
 * [new tag]         2.1.3      -> 2.1.3
 * [new tag]         2.1.4      -> 2.1.4
 * [new tag]         2.1.5      -> 2.1.5
 * [new tag]         2.1.6      -> 2.1.6
 * [new tag]         2.1.7      -> 2.1.7
 * [new tag]         2.1.8      -> 2.1.8
 * [new tag]         2.1.9      -> 2.1.9
HEAD is now at 2963bbec9 Merge pull request #6647 from tommyang/bump-revision-zsh-completion
Failed during: /usr/local/bin/brew update --force
[Kents-MacBook-Pro:/usr/local/bin] Kenny% brew update --force
brew: Command not found.
```

Comment: I am not at my mac at the moment but is `/bin/bash` hard-linked to `/bin/sh`?  If so the way to restore the system bash is to `sudo ln /bin/sh /bin/bash`.

Comment: @trojanfoe Doesn't seem to be, at least not on my 10.14.6 system. But you gave me the idea to boot into recovery and copy the bash binary from the recovery partition to /bin/bash, which worked :-) As such, +1 for you kind sir!

Comment: Cool.  Happy trails.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this must just be a quirk of `csh`. I doubt anyone else would ever be so stupid as to get themselves in a similar mess, but just in case, here's how I fixed it:

1. Boot into Recovery Mode (hold Command+R upon system boot). I was afraid to try this since I thought booting without `bash` present would be impossible, which it was if booting *normally*. But Recovery Mode uses an entirely-separate (hidden) partition on the HDD and as such, still contained a shiny, perfectly-working copy of bash 3.2.
2. Copy the aforementioned `bash` binary to your main partition (`cp /bin/bash /Volumes/<your volume name here, usually Macintosh HD by default>/bin/bash`). Remember to escape any spaces in the pathname with `\`, making the full command in my case `cp /bin/bash /Volumes/Mac\ OS\ X\ HD/bin/bash`.
3. Restart normally and ensure that `bash` is your default shell (`chsh -s /bin/bash`).
4. Continue running homebrew commands to your heart's content!